# Leaderboard implementation using Django

Tags: django

I have a model for every user on my site (UserProfile) each profile contains a field named points.

I would like to get the -5 +5 users from the current user while sorting by points. How can I accomplish this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make two queries, one for the users before the current users, and one for the users just after:

```
id = current_user.pk
points = current_user.profile.points

before = User.objects.filter(
    Q(profile__points__gt=points) | 
    Q(profile__points=points, pk__lt=id)
).order_by('-profile__points')[:5]

after = User.objects.filter(
    Q(profile__points__lt=points) | 
    Q(profile__points=points, pk__gt=id)
).order_by('profile__points')[:5]
```

This is bases on two queries:

- All users with a score greater than the current user, or with the same score but with a lower `pk`.
- All users with a score lower than the current user, or with the same score but with a greater `pk`.

Then with the proper ordering and limits you can get your result. Of course `pk` can be replaced by any other filed, or just removed altogether. In the latter case, you can instead consider that the current user is always first (this is just an example), and the queries become:

```
before = User.objects.filter(
    profile__points__gt=points,
).order_by('-profile__points')[:5]

after = User.objects.filter(
    profile__points__lte=points,
).exclude(pk=id).order_by('profile__points')[:5]
```

Alternatively, to get just the index of the current user in the list of users sorted by points, you could do:

```
id = current_user.pk
points = current_user.profile.points
index = User.objects.filter(
    Q(profile__points__gt=points) |
    Q(profile__points=points, pk__lt=id)
).count()
```

Then your list of users centered on the current one will just be:

```
User.objects.all().order_by('-profile__points', 'pk')[index - 5:index + 6]
```

This alternative could be slower if you have a lot of users, as the whole list of users before the current one needs to be evaluated, but I did not verify this.

Comment: That should work. any idea how can I get the "location" of the users in that order ?

Comment: @Nuno_147 You can count the number of users before the current one, I completed my answer with this alternative.

Comment: the Q(profile__points__gt=point) | Q(profile__points=points) can be changed to Q(profile__points_gte=point) right ?

Comment: Yes, but that's not what I wrote ;) In the example, the second `Q` has also a `pk__lt` parameter. Both will work fine, but the results will differ. With two `Q`s, the user's position relative to other users having the same score is determined by sorting on `pk`. With `Q(profile__points_gte=point)`, the current user is always last. With the latter option, if you want to use the index as an offset, you must also sort the results the same way, eg: `User.objects.all().extra(select={'is_current', 'user_id = %d' % current_user.pk}).order_by('-profile__points', 'is_current')[index - 5:index + 6]`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure what your points are but this should just be annotate, something like below...

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Avg

UserProfile.objects.annotate(sum_rating=Sum('sum__points')).order_by('-sum_points')
```

Don't forget you can use the annotation variable in a filter.

Update:
just order by points, note the `-`

```
UserProfile.objects.filter(whatever here).order_by('-points')[:5]
```

or

```
.order_by('points')[:5]
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt state that, But I dont need annotation because my points are calculated allready and are raw points. the challenge here is how should I get the +5-5 of some user points. I want his location in the leader-board and in addtion the 5 before him and the 5 after him.

Comment: Then filter by points and order by. You can then just get the top 5 of these results. For the last five do it in descending order.

Comment: my question was from a specific user not from top. I need to locate the user in the order and get the +5 -5.